Share "services" YAML across multiple jobs
I have a workflow with a job that starts up Postgres in a service container. The YAML looks something like this:
jobs:
  integration-tests:
    ...

    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    steps:
      ...

I have other jobs that need to set up Postgres in the same way. Right now I'm copy/pasting the above services YAML into those jobs as well, but that has all the problems of copy/paste. I'd like to avoid that and actually share the code.
GitHub Actions has two ways of sharing code: composite actions and reusable workflows. But I can't figure out how to use those mechanisms to share the services YAML.

Reusable Workflow
put your services job into a seperate workflow file, e.g. services.yml
and in other workflows you can call it
Caller:    
    if: ${{ (github.event_name == 'push' }}
    # Reusable services flow
    uses: ./.github/workflows/services.yml
     
      
   

